# SQL for setting criteria statment?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I want to set a criteria that will display only one result for 3143335.

Comment: Please include your expected output and also explain the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 0):

If your criteria/logic for selecting only one of the duplicate records with a Pass value of `3143335` could be the order of some other column, then you can use a `LIMIT` trick here, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Pass = 3143335
ORDER BY catalog
LIMIT 1;
```

This would choose the record with the "lowest" value for `catalog`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select "Pass","term","Status" 
From table 
where "Pass" = 3143335 
group by "Pass","term","Status"
```

Since your `catalog` and `Descr` columns are different, adding these to `select` or `group by` clause would cause more than one row to be returned.

Also, we don't know your table name.

Answer (score 0):

**In newer version of Mysql**

```
SELECT 
   pass, term, catalog, descp, status   
FROM 
   (SELECT 
   pass, term, catalog, descp, status, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY pass 
   ORDER BY catalog desc) row_num
    FROM 
       testtable
   ) temptable
WHERE 
   row_num = 1;
```

**In all version of Mysql**

```
SELECT 
   pass, term, catalog, descp, status
FROM 
   (
  select a.pass, a.term, a.catalog, a.descp, a.status,  count(*) as row_number 
  FROM testtable a
  JOIN testtable b ON a.pass = b.pass AND a.term >= b.term
  GROUP BY a.pass, a.term, a.catalog, a.descp, a.status
) temptable
WHERE 
  row_number = 1;
```